# Permutation in problems about the distribution of distinct objects.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

(In the following two problems the order of the objects in boxes matters)

**Problem 1.** We have five distinct objects and four distinct boxes. Second and third boxes must contain at least by one objects. How many ways are there?

*Solution:*

1. We treat all objects identical.
2. We fill second and third boxes by two objects.
3. We take 3-combinations from remaining 3 objects and three walls of boxes 6C3=20.
4. Then we say that five objects was distinct and there for we take permutation 5!=120.
5. And finally 20*120=2400.

I understand this solution. But why this does not work for the next problem?

Problem 2. We have ten distinct objects and four distinct boxes. Second and third boxes must contain at least by two objects. How many ways are there?

1. We treat all objects identical.
2. We fill second and third boxes by four objects.
3. We take 3-combinations from remaining 6 objects and three walls of boxes 9C3
4. Then we say that ten objects was distinct and there for we take permutation 10!
5. And finally 9C3*10! (which is wrong)

What is the problem here? What hidden idea do I not understand in the solution of the first problem? And what is the way to solve Problem 2 in the same way as Problem 1?

EDIT: This method is the shortcut from this problem from a textbook.

**Problem 3.** There are 11 men waiting for their turn in a barber
shop. Three particular men are A, B and C. There is a row of 11
seats for the customers. Find the number of ways of arranging them
so that no two of A, B and C are adjacent

*Solution:*(from textbook)  First of all, there are 3! ways to arrange A, B and C. Fix one of the ways, say A—B—C. We imagine that this three letters create four boxes ( _ *A_B_C* _ ). (MOMENT!) We then consider the remaining 8 persons.
Let us imagine tentatively that these 8 persons are identical, and
they are to be placed in 4 distinct boxes so
that boxes (2) and (3) are not vacant (since no two of A, B and C
are adjacent). To meet this requirement, we place one in box (2) and
one in box (3). Then the remaining six can be placed freely in the boxes in in 9C3 ways. But the eight persons are actually distinct. Thus, to each of these 9C3 ways, there are 8! ways to arrange them. Hence 3!*9C3*8!.

Comment: The underlying question is : why isn't your intuition telling you that these methods are wrong?  You can't study Probability theory or Combinatorics theory by memorizing formulas.  Instead, you have to stretch your intuition and obtain a deep understanding of the ideas.  In my opinion, your study of Probability/Combinatorics has *gone off the rails*.  I suggest that you find the right Math book for you, which contains many many exercises for you to learn from, open it to page 1, and attack.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your opinion. But your suggestion is the really what i am doing right now. In either way please excuse me dear station master.

Comment: Really.  You opened a book to page 1, and started working through the problems, came to this problem, and then posted what you think should be the right solution?  What is the name of the book that you are using?  Which page is this problem on?

Comment: @user2661923 1) Solution to Problem 3 is not my. It is from textbook.  2) The number of distributions of distinct objects n into different boxes m when the order matters is (n+m-1)!/(m-1)!.  The solution for Problem 1 is correct one. Do you really  understand the question?

Comment: No, as JMoravitz' answer indicates, the solution that you showed for the first problem, while it is good work, is wrong.  The error is subtle, and involves over-counting.  This explains my previous comment.  For example, suppose that initially, Box-2 gets Object-1, and then later, Box-2 also gets Object-2.  You are over-counting, treating this as distinct from Box-2 initially gets Object-2, and then later, Box-2 also gets Object-1.  I repeat, I think that your effort is good, but your intuition has not yet developed, and that you should find the right book and attack from page 1.

Comment: @user2661923 Which book(s) can you recommend for this? I need right book

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145261/discussion-between-user2661923-and-mokhmad-salekh-khekhaev).

Comment: Please click [this link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145261/discussion-between-user2661923-and-mokhmad-salekh-khekhaev) to join me in a chat room.

Answer (score 2):

"*But why this does not work for the next problem?*"  It shouldn't have worked for the first problem either.  There are only $4^5 = 1024$ ways to put five distinct objects in four distinct boxes in the first place, and fewer than that are of the type you prefer to have being such that the second and third boxes are guaranteed to have some objects in it.

"*What is the problem here?*"  For starters, by multiplying by $10!$ you are effectively implying the order of the objects *within* the boxes is important which traditionally is not meant to be the case.

For a correct solution, don't approach like this at all.  Use either inclusion-exclusion or use Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind (*as a way to disguise the inclusion-exclusion*) or come up with an argument by case-work.

Comment: Thanks! I mean distribution where the order of the objects in the box is matter. I added third problem for clarification. My initial post was bad shortcut.

Comment: There are 6720 ways to distribute 5 object into 4 boxes. And 2400 is the correct answer. Might be i had to add that the order in boxes matters in this distribution. But 4 in the power of 5 is 1024. So it is obvious what I did mean